# Duplicate declaration in current scope

Tags: debugging, excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using the below code to open a file and will be copying and pasting across data, however I am getting a compile error

```
Duplicate declaration in current scope
```

It is highlighting the wb As workbook line when it gives the compile error.

```
Sub Test()    
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range    
Set wksht = Sheets("CBS001")
Set rng = wksht.Range("A5")
If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
    Set rng = Range(rng.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 14), rng.Offset(1, 0))
Selection.Copy
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\Finance\CBF\Invoices\Monthly Invoicing Summary\" & Format(Now, "yyyy") & "\ASM\" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 1, Day(Now)), "mmyy") & " ASM CBF Reg Summary.xlsx")
wb.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Finance\CBF\Invoices\Monthly Invoicing Summary Test\" & Format(Now, "yyyy") & "\ASM\" & Format(Now, "mmyy") & " ASM CBF Reg Summary.xlsx"
wb.Close
End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the file name is duplicating

Comment: Have you also got a global variable named wb? This error usually means there is another variable of the same name that the system is trying to refer to at the same time.

Comment: Also check at the very top (at the beginning of the module) have you declared `wb` there?

Comment: I hadn't declared wb before but I just changed it to something else and it worked so not sure what's gone on there. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that vba was picking up the same Dim from elsewhere in my workbook, as such I am using longer, more accurate names.

```
  Sub Test()
  Dim wbdestination As Workbook
  Dim wksdata As Worksheet
  Dim rngdestination As Range
  End Sub
```

For examples